# Return value type does not match the function type CONST

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, constants

Not sure why error is happening on this function when I made the variable length const on a different function

```
int list::length() const {
return length;
}
```

CPP File Above

Header file BELOW

```
class list {

private:
struct Node
{
int info;
Node *next;

};


int length;
Node *head;


public:

list();
list(const list& otherlist);
~list();


int list::length() const;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you are qualifying `length()` inside your class. Remove `list::`. The second issue is that your member variable `length`, and your member function `length` are conflicting, because they have the same name.

I'd rename your members so that they don't clash with the functions. Consider `length_` and `head_`.

Edit: please also post compiler errors in the future, as it makes other readers' jobs a little easier :)